# How to rotate font awesome icon in react native?

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, font-awesome-5

In my react native application I have a font awesome icon. I want to rotate it. Help is needed.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View  } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

const InfoBox = () => {
    return (
          <View >
            <Icon name={'hand-holding-usd'} size={20}/>
          </View>

    )
}

export default InfoBox;
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `style` prop to rotate the icon. Change the degree/direction of rotation as required

```
<Icon name={'hand-holding-usd'}
      size={20}
      style={{transform: [{rotateY: '180deg'}]}}/>
```

Comment: After rotating how to position it to the left position. As after using transform the button goes to the right,

Comment: Thanks, man for your help. I solved my issue using this way. `<Icon name={'hand-holding-usd'} size={20} style={{transform: [{rotateY: '180deg'}],position: 'absolute',left:0}}/>`